# multiple file upload and single as well and to display all those files then

Tags: angular, file

I am trying to upload multiple files and to display those files as well but if in the first time user select first file and then again select two more files then it will overwrite first file to another two files. the way it should be to display 3 files. how can I fix that?

stackblitz link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gitter-hvt9w6

```
<div>
      <h2>file upload</h2>
      <input type="file" multiple (change)="onChange($event, showFileNames)" />
      <input #showFileNames />
      <button>upload</button>
    </div>




 onChange(event: any, input: any) {
    let files = [].slice.call(event.target.files);

    input.value = files.map(f => f.name).join(', ');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an additional "storage" variable and `concat` it with the selected files each time. :)
Warning: you will probably have to add some kind of detection as to whatever the files that you are trying to add to the "storage" aren't already there (might be better to use `forEach` on the files array and then `push` new elements to the "storage", check `Example 2`)

Example 1 (concat, no duplicates checking):

```
<div>
  <h2>file upload</h2>
  <input type="file" multiple (change)="onChange($event, showFileNames)" />
  <input #showFileNames />
  <button>upload</button>
</div>



storedFiles = [];
onChange(event: any, input: any) {
  let files = [].slice.call(event.target.files);
  this.storedFiles = this.storedFiles.concat(files);

  input.value = this.storedFiles.map(f => f.name).join(', ');
}
```

Example 2 (forEach and checking file name for duplicates)

```
storedFiles = [];
onChange(event: any, input: any) {
  let files = [].slice.call(event.target.files);
  files.forEach((file) => {
    let found = false;
    for (let i = 0; i < this.storedFiles.length; i++){
      if (file.name == this.storedFiles[i].name){
        found = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (!found) this.storedFiles.push(file);
  });

  input.value = this.storedFiles.map(f => f.name).join(', ');
}
```

I loop over storedFiles with a regular for loop, rather than the forEach loop to be able to short-circuit (`break`) it, since if one duplicate is found you don't need to search for another.

Comment: but it will still overwrite the first file.